# states and city not populated in dropdown

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular and am encountering problems with a dynamic dropdown of country states and cities. Although I have checked whole lot of answers in StackOverflow I am not able to get a clear picture as to how we should successfully code to get the desired results.

```
countries: {};
states: {};
cities: {};

ngOnInit() {
    this.getCountry()
}

<div class="form-group">
                <select formControlName="country" class="form-control" (change)="onChangeCountry($event.target.value)">
                  <option value="">Select country...</option>
                  <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country.id">{{country?.name}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <select formControlName="state" class="form-control" 
           (change)="onChangeState($event.target.value)">
                  <option value="">Select state...</option>
                  <option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state.id">{{state?.name}}</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <select formControlName="city" class="form-control">
                  <option value="">Select city...</option>
                  <option *ngFor="let city of cities" [value]="city.id">{{city?.name}}</option>
                </select>
              </div>


 getCountry(){
    this._country.getCountries().subscribe((res: any) =>{
        this.countries = res.data;
    });
}
onChangeCountry(countryId: number) {
  if (countryId) {
    this._country.getStates(countryId).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data)
        this.states = data;
        this.cities = null;
      }
    );
  } else {
    this.states = null;
    this.cities = null;
  }
}
onChangeState(stateId: number) {
  if (stateId) {
    this._country.getCities(stateId).subscribe(
      data => 
      this.cities = data
    );
  } else {
    this.cities = null;
  }
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: cities should be a list

Comment: `this.states = data;` should be `this.states = data.data;` and `this.cities = data;` should be `this.cities = data.data;`

Comment: Property 'data' does not exist on type -- getting this error @SivakumarTadisetti

Comment: @Abid but in the images you shared has `data` property right?

Comment: In both the subscriptions, can you do `console.log(data)` and post here the images?

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti{message: "states found", data: Array(7)}
data: Array(7)
0: {id: 487, name: "Encamp", country_id: 6, country_code: "AD", fips_code: "03", …}

Comment: @Abid I think when you change state, you are getting different response ` data: Array(7) 0: {id: 487, name: "Encamp", country_id: 6, country_code: "AD", fips_code: "03", …}` then `onChangeState` subscription you just need `this.cities = data`

Comment: And can you do console.log(data) before `this.cities = data`

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti if possible pls join this am very in angular To join the video meeting, click this link: https://meet.google.com/akc-udaa-qsy

Comment: i added console.log(data) but i was getting error -- Property 'data' does not exist on type 'RegisterComponent'.

Comment: @Abid can you join the call

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti yes pls

Comment: https://meet.google.com/akc-udaa-qsy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this for the init of the variables,

```
countries: any[] = [];
states: any[] = [];
cities: any[] = [];
```

Replace any with what type is each variable.

Answer (score 1):

In the image you added, you could see that "states found" message is printed in the console.. So the response object is identified correctly. Inside the state object **data** is the array that hold the list of states.. right? So you need to iterate through **states.data** instead of states. Apply similar change to **cities** and **countries** objects as well..

```
<option *ngFor="let state of states.data" [value]="state.id">{{state?.name}}</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the entire object to states variable instead of the array of states in that object.
Change the data being assigned to states in onChangeCountry from:

```
this.states = data;
```

to:

```
this.states = data.data;
```

Likewise, do similar change for cities assignment in onChangeState.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you really need to message: 'countries found' because you are not using it. Better idea is to return directly the array of countries for example if you are working on the server side also.

```
countries: Country[] = [];

private getCountry(): void {
      this._country.getCountries()
          .subscribe(response => this.countries = response.data.data);
}
```

If you really need that message field, then leave countries like an object, but change the name if is an object not an array and in html template use like this:

## in .ts

```
public country: Country;
```

## in .html

```
*ngFor="let country of country.data"
```